# Read regiondata as rectangles

Tags: c#, drawing, region

I have a Region, from which I am subtracting n number of Rectangles, now I need to get all the remaining space in terms of rectangles. Is there a way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should realize that any set of rectangles you get may be an approximation if the region contains any curves.

Second, try calling [GetRegionScans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.getregionscans.aspx) with an indentity matrix.

```
RectangleF[] rects = region.GetRegionScans(new Matrix());
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is it possible to get the rectangles in smallest possible form?

Comment: Actually, it is returning the rectangles horizontally, if I can get rectangles vertically in another pass should do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Rotate the region 90 degrees, get the scan rects, and then rotate back.

Comment: Then I have to rotate back the scanned rectangles individually right?

Comment: Yes, using a rotation matrix with an opposite angle.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to rotate rectangles without using Graphics? The only way I found to do it is using g.RotateTransform which doesn't return the coordinate of the rectangle.

Comment: You could write your own matrix but that would be redundant. Just add an extension method on `Matrix` that transforms a `RectangleF`.